# Chains and antichains in a family of sets

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S$ be a family of sets with inclusion as partial order.
Suppose $S$ contains the empty set. Is $\{\emptyset\}$ an antichain?
Also, take a non-empty set $X$ in $S$. Is $\{X\}$ a chain (and/or) an antichain?

Since the question seems to be a bit unclear, let me clarify it with an example.
Let $F=\{\emptyset, \{1,2,3\}\}$ and consider $F$ as a poset ordered by inclusion. My definition of a (anti)chain $A$ is that it is a SET of elements of a poset such that every element in $A$ is (in)comparable. Now $\{1,2,3\}$ is not a chain of $F$ (it is not a set containing some elements of $F$), but is $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ a chain/antichain?
Is $\{\emptyset\}$ an antichain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one-element subset of a poset is always both a chain and an antichain: Any two distinct elements are both comparable and uncomparable.

Comment: Thank you, what about the question regarding the empty set? I.e. is the empty set "contained" in the empty set? (And so $\{\emptyset\}$ would become both a chain and an antichain).

Comment: @dado: Yes, $\{\varnothing\}$ is both a chain and an antichain in that partial order, for exactly the reason that Hagen gave.

Answer (score 1):

No, $\{\emptyset\}$ is (trivially) a chain, since every pair of elements in it is comparable.

It seems to me that every pair of elements in {{1,2,3}} is comparable.

Comment: Ok, I try to be more precise. Say, $F=\{\emptyset, \{1\}\}$ and I make $F$ into a poset with inclusion. My definition of a (anti)chain $A$ is that it is a SET of elements of a poset such that every element in $A$ is (in)comparable. Now $\{1\}$ is not a chain of $F$ (it is not a set containing some elements of $F$), but is $\{\{1\}\}$ a chain/antichain?

Comment: Ok- I did wonder if that was what you meant.

Comment: Not meaning to be fussy, but I think $\{1\}$ is a set containing the element 1 of $F$. However, your question did say {${X}$} and {$\emptyset$}, which do mean the set containing X and the set containing the empty set, as I understand it: I just decided to assume you meant X and $\emptyset$ first time around.

Comment: 1 is not an element of $F$. The elements of $F$ are $\emptyset$ and $\{1\}$.

Comment: Oh yes: I see now: thanks